# Detecting if ssh login fails

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I have this line to run in a script, the issue is that I have to run the script over several hosts ( and it includes windows servers) and I don't know how to catch the error if the ssh receives something like "port 22: Connection refused" or access denied:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@$1 ARG1=$1 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH'
 commands
 echo "login is OK in $ARG1"
ENDSSH
```

Comment: I, for one, believe you.

Comment: To expand on @mikeserv's presumably tongue-in-cheek comment: what is your question? What outcome do you observe that is not as you would like it to be?

Answer (score 1):

let me guess

```
#!/bin/bash

if  ssh user@$1 ARG1=$1 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH'
  commands
  echo "login is OK in $ARG1"
ENDSSH
then true
else
  echo not good
fi
```

please note that

- the last command with the shell must return true
- if ssh fail to connect, you'll go to `echo not good` part of script

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. But, also, if, lets say, there are two commands to run in the server and one of them its not working, how can I "trap" it and echo it?. I mean, something like this:
    PIDS=`ps -ef | grep -i PatrolAgent`
    if [ -z "$PIDS" ]; then
    echo "Process is not running."
     exit 1
    else
      if [ $X -eq 4 ]
       then
       echo "Restart the process in $target"
       echo $!
       fi
    fi

with this I'm getting only "Restart the process in "